# crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated. I believe chrome.runtime.getURL() is causing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am building a google chrome extension in react. What I am trying to do now is that in the popup window there will be a button that when clicked, opens up a new panel window (an extension page) and in this page I will be displaying stuff and more buttons etc.

This error is coming from the button click to open new panel part. So I have the manifest.json link the default_popup to 'index.html' which is empty. (apart from the html5 skeleton)

I have my App.js file that holds all of the code for performing the above actions:
`

```
/*global chrome*/
import './App.css';
import React, { Component, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

let createData = {
  //type: 'panel',
  width: 350,
  height: 500,
  url: chrome.runtime.getURL('./src/newPage.html')
}

function App() {

  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleClick = event => {

      let creating = chrome.windows.create(createData);
      creating.then(() => {
        console.log("The detached panel has been created");
      })
    };

    const element = ref.current;

    element.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

    return () => {
      element.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <body>
      <div>
        <h1>Tester Extension</h1>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button ref={ref}>Click</button>
      </div>
    </body>
  );

export default App;
```

`
newPage.html contains the layout of the extension page. however I get the "crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated." in the console of the extension page and the following screen upon it opening

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ru8lI.png)

When I take away the url part of the following code
`

```
let createData = {
  //type: 'panel',
  width: 350,
  height: 500,
  url: chrome.runtime.getURL('./src/newPage.html')
}
```

`
the error goes away but then I am not sure how to do what I want to.

I have looked through a bunch of the other posts with similar error message and tried all of the different fixes but nothing has worked apart from the solution just mentioned.

Any advice on moving forward would be great

Comment: Assuming this is inside the web page, the problem is that you didn't add the path `/src/newPage.html` to [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) or you didn't reload the extension/tab after doing so. But if this is an extension page, the problem is that the path is incorrect - check your dist directory and use a relative path inside. The crbug error is unrelated to your code, it's shown by Chrome's internal implementation of the error page UI.

Comment: @wOxxOm This is an extension page, but I do not have a dist directory. I have only 
-build
-node_modules
-public
-src
.gitignore
package-lock.json
package.json
README.md

Comment: dist and build are synonyms, it's the directory of the compiled/built extension.